# NewtonSoft JSON converter serializes but does it weirdly. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, vb.net, json.net

Given the following object

```
Friend Class GetLocationsResult
    Public Property X1 As String
    Public Property X2 As String
    Public Property X3 As String
    Public Property X4 As String
    Public Property X5 As String
    Public Property X6 As Double
    Public Property X7 As Double
End Class
```

And it is declared and instantiated thusly:

```
Dim objList as List(of GetLocationsResults) = new List(of GetLocationsResults)
```

And objList is populated via an iterator that churns through a collection of objects/aggregate classes. The iterator just shoves values into a new GetLocationsResult object and then adds it to the list.

And given the NewtonSoft `JSONConvert.SerializeObject(objList)` results:

`{"d":"[{\"X1\":\"Store Name\",\"X2\":\"Address\",\"X3\":\"City\",\"X4\":\"State\",\"X5\":\"Zip\",\"X6\":Coord1,\"X7\":Coord2}]"}`

> *This point has been addressed and is no longer an issue*
>
> There are several issues with this result set. First, for whatever odd
>   reason, the object being named `"d"` is not acceptable.
>
> 1. How can I specify something other than `"d"` for the "name" of the json array?

When I attempt to `JSON.parse` the response, it needs to be in the following format in order to actually get to the data:

```
resultSet = JSON.parse(data.d);
console.warn(resultSet[0].X1);
```

Having to say `resultSet[0]` is, of course, not acceptable.

> 2. How do I cause the 'JSONConvert.Serialize' method to not wrap the response in such a way that I have to refer to the first index of the
>      resulting JSON data so that I can say `resultSet.X1` instead of
>      `resultSet[0].X1`?

---

As requested, here is some more detailed information that may be relevant to the issue at hand.

The data is being returned from a WCF service. The exposed method is decorated thusly:

```
<WebInvoke(Method:="GET", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)>
```

and returns type `String`. The service is being consumed by a desktop application and a mobile platform. The desktop website can have its own method and, in fact, does because we don't want to deal with X1, X2, etc while the mobile platform devs have declared that as necessary. As noted, the method returns a number of results in the form of a custom, aggregate class which is then shoved into a class object which is only a collection of properties. The return statement is thus:

```
Return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(retVal)
```

where retVal is a List(of GetLocationsResult)

So while having to access the data via index may be fine for the website, it is not acceptable for the mobile platform. Because each will run their own methods, it is possible to have a unique solution for both if needed.

Comment: Post the GetLocationsResultObject Object. Although the fix can be inferred from the problems, posting the Object will help confirm it.

Comment: That would be the `Friend Class GetLocationsResult` Object at the very top, first code block. :)

Comment: `{"d":"[...` there is no closing `]`

Comment: I have corrected the json brackets and braces and quotes. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You don't show the code where you instantiate the variable `GetLocationsResultObject`.  Is that just an instance of the type `GetLocationsResult`, or is it an array / list of those objects?

Comment: It is a class object and I'm just running an iterator to shove values into a list of type GetLocationsResult. I will clarify

Comment: This is not odd or weird, just modern day json. the format prevents malicious execution, see [this](http://encosia.com/a-breaking-change-between-versions-of-aspnet-ajax/#comment-34045) for explanation

Comment: Using the code posted, my result is d-free: `"{"X1":"foo","X2":null,"X3":null,"X4":null,"X5":"bar","X6":-25.3,"X7":-32.7}"`

Comment: @WhiteHat: Please post that as an answer as it addresses one major issue that I came here for. Thanks.

Comment: @Plutonix: it does it in some instances. See the link WhiteHat posted in his comment right above yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things.

1. It sounds like you're returning that back through an ASP.NET ASMX
   `ScriptService` or ASPX `[WebMethod]`. When using one of those
   endpoints, [you don't need to (and shouldn't) manually serialize the
   object into JSON](http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/). ASP.NET will do that for you automatically. You don't need to use JSONConvert at all; just return your object as the result. That's why you're seeing all that escaped data after the `.d`. It's JSON serialized twice.
2. As WhiteHat mentioned, the `.d` is a good thing in some situations. It's introduced by default in these ASP.NET JSON services and can't easily be removed on the server-side, but is easy to account for when you parse the response on the client-side.
3. You are returning a `List(of GetLocationResults)`, which maps to a JavaScript array. That's why you need to use `resultSet[0].X1` to access a value in the result. If you want to access that value via resultSet.X1, you need to be sure to return only a single `GetLocationResults` object instead of a List of them.

Does that help? If you could update your question with a more complete example of your server-side and client-side code, I could give you an example of how to address the preceding three issues.

Comment: I have added more information for you that might help. The `GetLocationsResults` object is just a class object and newtonsoft `jsonconvert.serializeOjbect` turns that into an array nicely and was, in fact, why it was done this way. See if that added info helps any. Thanks.

Comment: After taking a closer look at the mobile requirements (see edit), they're going to have to deal with that index. It turns out that I don't need to JSONConvert the response, just return the list(of object) and it gets converted to json for me. Last time I remember working with JSOn from a webservice, you had to convert and do this and that and now suddenly you just return your object and *poof* it's handled automagically. Thanks.

Comment: @MetalPhoenix: That's right. Returning the object directly is the correct approach (see the link in my answer for more info on why that is).